# How to detect the presence of an element with Selenium Webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Selenium WebDriver's `findElement()` function to detect if an element is present on a page. No matter what I do, Selenium exits the code even if I throw the WebDriverException.

I tried using this code, but it didn't prevent Selenium from exiting:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath) != null){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
    System.out.println("Element is Present");
}else{
    System.out.println("Element is Absent");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

`isDisplayed()` also seems to have a similar error. Am I just using the wrong methods or am I using the methods incorrectly?

Comment: Use driver.findElements(). plural form. which will return a list. check size. findElement throws an exception if element not present.

Comment: @Grasshopper It worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: Why the downvotes, I don't want my new account banned, I thought I had a good question that I couldn't find an answer that worked for me.

Comment: @KenBone A single downvote won't cause much harm - to get banned, one should get A LOT of downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use findElements. I wrote you an example below:

```
public WebElement element(WebDriver driver) {
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath"));
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        return list.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
element.click();
```

Comment: worked perfectly, I don't know why WebDriver doesn't throw the exception properly but this will do.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a method to wait for the element and return a true or false if it's present or not present. This should do that for you -

```
public boolean isElementPresent(final String xpath) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    try {
    return wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isDisplayed()) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });         
    } catch (NoSuchElementException | TimeoutException e) {         
        System.out.println("The wait timed out, couldnt not find element");
        return false;
    }               
}
```

That's going to try for 30 seconds to see if the element is present or not. Change the timeout from 30 to however long you want to wait for it.

Then from your main code send the xpath as a string to that method and do something when it comes back with true:

```
if (isElementPresent("xpath")) {
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
} else {
    System.out.println("Can't click on the element because it's not there");
}
```

So essentially,

if isElementPresent == true --> Click on the element 
Else --> Print some stuff out.